# JS - Converting with toFixed and back not the same number

Tags: math, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I'm converting numbers from an input box with JS. I'm using .toFixed(2) in order to truncate the numbers, but then when I convert back, it's now working.

Example: original input value is is 100

I then convert from bbl to m3 using my formula:

```
oldVal = jQuery(this).val();
oldVal = parseFloat(oldVal);
newConvertedVal = parseFloat((oldVal * 0.1589873).toFixed(2));
jQuery(this).val(newConvertedVal);
```

This works fine and I get my result of 5.90

When I convert back, however, using the reverse formula:

```
oldVal = jQuery(this).val();
oldVal = parseFloat(oldVal);
newConvertedVal = parseFloat((oldVal / 0.1589873).toFixed(2));
jQuery(this).val(newConvertedVal);
```

When I convert back, however, I get 100.01

There's that extra .01 in there.

I don't want to round the number because in some case converting accurately may require the number to be a float. Is there a better way to convert back exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If by “convert back exactly,” you mean you want the result of converting in one direction with a multiplication by .1589873, with rounding to the nearest 100<sup>th</sup>, and converting in the reverse direction with a division by .1589873 to produce the original input, this is not possible.

Rounding to the nearest 100<sup>th</sup> discards information. In particular, the conversion maps some different numbers to one result.

For example, consider converting both 100 and 100.01:

- 100 • .1589873 = 15.89873. Rounding to the nearest .01 produces 15.90.
- 100.01 • .1589873 = 15.900319873. Rounding to the nearest .01 produces 15.90.

Therefore, from the conversion result 15.90, it is not possible to determine whether the original input was 100 or 100.01. No computation can definitely produce the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks. I get this, but is there  a best practices way of converting back and forth while only showing the end user the number to the second decimal place?